# for loop with assignment in php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, variable-assignment

When I want to iterate an array I usually do:

```
foreach ($array as $a)
{
   //do something with $a
}
```

I just want to know if is possible do something like this with a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $a = $array[$i]; $i ++)
{
   //do something with $a
}
```

Edit: When I test the code above, the for syntax is not valid.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if you get the same results?

Comment: Why? Can't you just assign `$a` inside the loop?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, obviouly I have tried the code, and it is not a valid expression

Comment: Just looking it up in the manual would've been faster than typing this question.

Comment: @manix Where does it say that in your post ?

Comment: Apologies, after read it again the post was incompleted.  I take for known some facts.

Comment: I've answered it below. What is reason that you have to do in that manner with a for-loop instead of a foreach-loop ?

Comment: Just to make a one-line declaration, by this way I have control of `index` and the object indexed in the array. With the foreach I only have the control of the object of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skip the $a = $array[$i] part of the for-loop (This is assigned INSIDE of the loop and not in the declaration of the loop)

You should do like this instead:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i ++)
{
   $a = $array[$i]; //Gets value of element in array $array
   //Do something with it...
}
```

You say you want control of the element of an array. 
You can do the equalivalent by doing like this (adding a key-value to the foreach-loop)

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$i)
{
   $a = $i[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the third semicolon with a comma. It's not the entire solution (assignment is done too late), but it should explain sufficiently how a for statement works.

Comment: Ok, now I have this topic more clear: looks like `for loop` only accept `boolean` conditions at the declaration

Comment: Ok, for example, I think that for loop is based in this concept: `for(|inicialization| |condition| |counter|)`. So, I had no problem in adding more conditions (returning boolean values), for example:  `for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); true; $i ++)`

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop doesn't need to handle the `$a = $array[$i];` as part of its arguments.
You can just move it to the body of the loop, something like this:
`for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

    $a = $array[$i];
    //do something with $a
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array);  $i ++){
    $a = $array[$i];
}
```

The for loop definition takes three statements you provided four. Move the assignment of $a into the actual loop.